# Android Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android

Estou com esse erro e não consigo saber como resolver.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.resources
>   android.view.View.getResources()' on a null object reference

Esse é o codigo do `actCadCliente`:

```js
package com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.database.DadosOpenHelper;
import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.dominio.entidades.Cliente;
import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.dominio.repositorio.ClienteRepositorio;

public class ActCadCliente extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText edtNome;
  private EditText edtEndereco;
  private EditText edtEmail;
  private EditText edtTelefone;
  private ConstraintLayout layoutContentActCadCliente;

  private ClienteRepositorio clienteRepositorio;

  private SQLiteDatabase conexao;

  private DadosOpenHelper dadosOpenHelper;

  private Cliente cliente;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_cad_cliente);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
    edtEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEndereco);
    edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    edtTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTelefone);

    layoutContentActCadCliente = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutContentActCadCliente);

    criarConexao();
  }

  private void criarConexao() {

    try {

      dadosOpenHelper = new DadosOpenHelper(this);

      conexao = dadosOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

      Snackbar.make(layoutContentActCadCliente, R.string.message_conexao_criada_com_sucesso, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction(R.string.lbl_ok, null).show();


      clienteRepositorio = new ClienteRepositorio(conexao);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

      android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      dlg.setTitle(R.string.title_erro);
      dlg.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
      dlg.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_ok, null);
      dlg.show();

    }
  }

  private void confirmar() {

    cliente = new Cliente();

    if (validaCampos() == false) {

      try {

        clienteRepositorio.inserir(cliente);

        finish();

      } catch (Exception ex) {

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlg.setTitle(R.string.title_erro);
        dlg.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        dlg.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_ok, null);
        dlg.show();

      }

    }



  }

  @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
  private boolean validaCampos() {

    boolean res = false;

    String nome = edtNome.getText().toString();
    String endereco = edtEndereco.getText().toString();
    String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
    String telefone = edtTelefone.getText().toString();


    if (res = isCampoVazio(nome)) {
      edtNome.requestFocus();
    } else
    if (res = isCampoVazio(endereco)) {
      edtEndereco.requestFocus();
    } else
    if (res = !isEmailValido(email)) {
      edtEmail.requestFocus();
    } else
    if (res = isCampoVazio(telefone)) {
      edtTelefone.requestFocus();
    }

    if (res) {

      AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      dlg.setTitle("Aviso");
      dlg.setMessage(R.string.message_campos_invalidos_brancos);
      dlg.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_ok, null);
      dlg.show();

    }

    return res;

  }

  private boolean isCampoVazio(String valor) {

    boolean resultado = (TextUtils.isEmpty(valor) || valor.trim().isEmpty());
    return resultado;
  }

  private boolean isEmailValido(String email) {

    boolean resultado = (!isCampoVazio(email) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches());
    return resultado;

  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_act_cad_cliente, menu);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {

      case R.id.action_ok:
        validaCampos();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Botão OK Selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;

      case R.id.action_cancelar:

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Botão OK Selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();

        break;



    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

`actMain` :

```js
package com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.database.DadosOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ActMain extends AppCompatActivity {

  private RecyclerView lstDados;
  private FloatingActionButton fab;
  private ConstraintLayout layoutContentMain;

  private SQLiteDatabase conexao;

  private DadosOpenHelper dadosOpenHelper;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    lstDados = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lstDados);

    layoutContentMain = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutContentMain);

    criarConexao();

  }

  private void criarConexao() {

    try {

      dadosOpenHelper = new DadosOpenHelper(this);

      conexao = dadosOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

      Snackbar.make(layoutContentMain, R.string.message_conexao_criada_com_sucesso, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction(R.string.action_ok, null).show();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

      AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      dlg.setTitle(R.string.title_erro);
      dlg.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
      dlg.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_ok, null);
      dlg.show();

    }
  }

  public void cadastrar(View view) {

    Intent it = new Intent(ActMain.this, ActCadCliente.class);
    startActivity(it);

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_act_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

`ClienteRepositorio`:

```js
package com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.dominio.repositorio;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.betelhosting.dev.carteiradecliente.dominio.entidades.Cliente;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Felipe Tomaz Rebeca, dev.betelhosting.com/i
 */

public class ClienteRepositorio {

  private SQLiteDatabase conexao;

  public ClienteRepositorio(SQLiteDatabase conexao) {
    this.conexao = conexao;
  }

  public void inserir(Cliente cliente) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("NOME", cliente.nome);
    contentValues.put("ENDERECO", cliente.endereco);
    contentValues.put("EMAIL", cliente.email);
    contentValues.put("TELEFONE", cliente.telefone);

    conexao.insertOrThrow("CLIENTE", null, contentValues);

  }

  public void excluir(int codigo) {

    String[] parametros = new String[1];
    parametros[0] = String.valueOf(codigo);

    conexao.delete("CLIENTE", "CODIGO = ?", parametros);

  }

  public void alterar(Cliente cliente) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("NOME", cliente.nome);
    contentValues.put("ENDERECO", cliente.endereco);
    contentValues.put("EMAIL", cliente.email);
    contentValues.put("TELEFONE", cliente.telefone);

    String[] parametros = new String[1];
    parametros[0] = String.valueOf(cliente.codigo);

    conexao.update("CLIENTE", contentValues, "CODIGO = ?", parametros);

  }

  public List < Cliente > buscarTodos() {
    List < Cliente > clientes = new ArrayList < Cliente > ();

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(" SELECT CODIGO, NOME, ENDERECO, EMAIL, TELEFONE ");
    sql.append("   FROM CLIENTE ");

    Cursor resultado = conexao.rawQuery(sql.toString(), null);

    if (resultado.getCount() > 0) {

      resultado.moveToFirst();

      do {

        Cliente cli = new Cliente();


        cli.codigo = resultado.getInt(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CODIGO"));
        cli.nome = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NOME"));
        cli.endereco = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ENDERECO"));
        cli.email = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("EMAIL"));
        cli.telefone = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TELEFONE"));

        clientes.add(cli);

      } while (resultado.moveToNext());

    }



    return clientes;
  }

  public Cliente buscarCliente(int codigo) {

    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(" SELECT CODIGO, NOME, ENDERECO, EMAIL, TELEFONE ");
    sql.append("   FROM CLIENTE ");
    sql.append(" WHERE CODIGO = ?");

    String[] parametros = new String[1];
    parametros[0] = String.valueOf(cliente.codigo);

    Cursor resultado = conexao.rawQuery(sql.toString(), null);

    if (resultado.getCount() > 0) {

      resultado.moveToFirst();

      cliente.codigo = resultado.getInt(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CODIGO"));
      cliente.nome = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NOME"));
      cliente.endereco = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ENDERECO"));
      cliente.email = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("EMAIL"));
      cliente.telefone = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TELEFONE"));

      return cliente;

    }

    return null;


  }

}
```

desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Quando que o seu erro é levantado, você precisa nos explicar em qual ação de sua aplicação é dado o erro. Em alguns casos, adicionar o código e mostrar o erro não ajuda muita coisa.

Comment: quando eu entro na view de cadastro...bem eu ainda não sei fazer perguntas mt claras sobre android pq eu sou iniciante nessa linguagem...

Comment: **não está clara o suficiente** - Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Comment: eu preciso corrigir isso pq sabado eu vou entregar ele...